# Does this sort algorithm already exists?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, search, binary

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> arr;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    arr.push_back(rand() % 100000);

  //algorithm ----
  vector<int> sorted;
  sorted.push_back(arr[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
    //case: element is smaller than the smallest sorted element
    if (arr[i] < sorted[0]) {
      sorted.insert(sorted.begin(), arr[i]);
      continue;
    }
    //case: element is inside the sorted elements, search where
    if (arr[i] < sorted[sorted.size() - 1]) {

      //linear search, really slow
      // for (int j = 0; j < sorted.size() - 1; ++j) {
      //     if (sorted[j] < arr[i] && arr[i] < sorted[j + 1]) {
      //         sorted.insert(sorted.begin() + j, arr[i]);
      //     }
      // }

      //binary search
      int low, mid, high;
      low = 0;
      high = sorted.size() - 2;
      while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if ( (sorted[mid] < arr[i] && arr[i] < sorted[mid + 1]) 
          || sorted[mid] == arr[i] 
          || sorted[mid + 1] == arr[i]) {
          sorted.insert(sorted.begin() + mid, arr[i]);
          break;
        }
        if (sorted[mid] < arr[i])
          low = mid + 1;
        else
          high = mid - 1;
      }
      if (low > high) {
        for (auto x : sorted)
          cout << x << " ";
        cout << "\nsomething broke!\n";
      }
    }
    //case: the element is larger than the largest sorted element
    //goes to the end
    else {
      sorted.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  //----

  for(auto x : sorted)
    cout << x << " ";
  cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The other day, I got and idea about a sort algorithm implementing binary search, here is the code in c++11.

My question is had somebody already made an algorithm like this, or is this even a usable algorithm?

I think it is around O(n Log n), but I don't know what is the complexity of insert and push_back functions.

Any help is appreciated. ;)

I also included the version with linear search, it's maybe a bit easier to understand, but really slow.

Comment: it's too similar to quicksort!

Comment: push_back is generally O(1)
insert can be up to O(n).

Comment: @AlexG Depends on if the vector needs to reallocate or not.

Comment: push_back is O(1) if no allocation happend

Comment: Insert at the beginning of the vector has to move all its elements one down. This causes O(n) complexity even if no reallocation is needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's why I said "generally". In this case, it would be trivial to reserve the right amount of space thus getting the O(1).

Comment: My napkin notes tells me this is a O(N²log N) algorithm, arr.size\*sorted.insert\*bin_search. So not really comparable to any regular sort.

Comment: Hmm, is there any way to eliminate that sorted.insert, so it works more efficiently?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I think its O(N*(N+log N)) which is O(N²).

Answer (score 3):

I would say that this is a (reinvented perhaps) version of insertion sort. 
See this:

[Insertion Sort on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Comment: Agreed, it is an out of place insertion sort with a binary search + sorted.insert that ineffectively duplicates the work of the regular insertion sorts insert.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is kind of like this in a long fashion

```
if (arr.size() < 2)
  return arr;
for (auto i = std::next(arr.begin()); i != arr.end(); ++i) {
    std::rotate(std::upper_bound(arr.begin(), i, *i), i, i+1);
}
```

Doing an inplace insertion sort, which is O(N²).

Now lets look at your contribution

```
if (arr.size() < 2)
  return arr;
for (auto i = std::next(arr.begin()); i != arr.end(); ++i) {
    if (*i < *arr.begin())
      std::rotate(arr.begin(), i, i+1);
    else 
      if (*i > *std::prev(i)) // already in the right spot
        continue;
    std::rotate(std::upper_bound(arr.begin(), i, *i), i, i+1);
}
```

So is it worth it we are gaining the cost of `std::upper_bound` which is log N, each time the if's are correct, so 2 `if`'s cost where its not the case. So on a randomly ordered list the cases where the `if`'s help us will rapidly diminish as it would be 1/n for each, in the case of a nearly sorted list or a nearly reverse sorted list you would win some, but in all other case its just a waste of time.